# Difference between System.Convert.ToInt64() and Convert.ToInt64()

Tags: .net

Explain with Example if possible....
For example

```
   int s=System.Convert.ToInt64(txtno.Text);
   int k=Convert.ToInt64(txtno.Text);
```

Comment: there is no difference.  They are the same thing.

Comment: remove the `using System;` at the beginning of your file to understand the difference

Comment: One assigns to `s` and one assigns to `k` :p

Comment: In the second case, `Convert` can refer to an other class than `System.Convert`. That would be epic codesmell though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same.

On top of the file you have the line

```
using System;
```

That means that when you use types and classes defined in the System namespace, you do not need to specify "System" explicitly.
Thus, `System.Convert` and `Convert` refer to exactly the same thing, the latter is just shorter to write.

Answer (score 1):

They are exactly the same, a [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sf0df423%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (using System) makes leaving off the System qualifier possible.

Answer (score 0):

None. Its the same. (if you not define a Convert class in your namespace).